# How to boot Sabayon linux with isoboot= and overlayfs parameters?

Tags: grub2, sabayon

https://bugs.sabayon.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4941

I don't understand, how sabayon's initrd image is created. (I am just installing that system for the first time!).

When I am trying parameters from instruction https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Sabayon
I receive errors about unability to use aufs.

How the parameter isoboot= is implemented in Sabayon? How it supposed to work in details? Which program in initrd performs iso mounting? How squashfs is named and how initrd is supposed to find it? What happened to aufs, was it replaced with overlayfs?

UPD: Sabayon uses genkernel-next, here is it's parameters description:
https://github.com/Sabayon/genkernel-next/blob/master/doc/genkernel.8.txt#L387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bug about docs:
https://bugs.sabayon.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4941

list of ramdisk options is documented there:
https://github.com/Sabayon/genkernel-next/blob/master/doc/genkernel.8.txt#L387

```
menuentry "Live ISO, Sabayon_MATE (2015-05-15a)" {
  insmod loopback
  set isofile=/iso/Sabayon_MATE_20150515/Sabayon_Linux_DAILY_amd64_MATE-dev.iso
  loopback loop (${root})${isofile}
  linux (loop)/boot/sabayon root=/dev/ram0 init=/linuxrc isoboot=${isofile} cdroot looptype=squashfs loop=/livecd.squashfs overlayfs
  initrd (loop)/boot/sabayon.igz
}
```